# JavaCV - Use an threshold image to look for a Convex shape contour

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, javacv

I'm developing a shape identification project using JavaCV and I have found some OpenCV code to identify convex shapes in a particular threshold image. I have tried to convert it from openCV to javaCV. But when i run the code, it stucked in the while look checking for contours. Anyone can help to find the error? Thanks.

```
IplImage detectThrs = getThresholdImage(img);

                System.err.println("Stucked!!");

                CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

                CvSeq contour = new CvSeq(null);

                cvFindContours(detectThrs, storage, contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                System.err.println("Stucked 2 !!");
                CvSeq approx = null;
                CvRect bound = null;
                CvRect boundMax = null;
                CvRect pos = null;

                while (contour != null && !contour.isNull()) {
                    System.err.println("Stucked in while!!");
                    bound = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);
                    approx = cvApproxPoly(contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contour) * 0.02, 0);

                    if(cvCheckContourConvexity(approx) != 0){
                        if(bound.width() > 4 || bound.height() > 4){

                            cvRectangle(
                                    detectThrs,
                                    cvPoint(bound.x(), bound.y()),
                                    cvPoint(bound.x()+bound.width(), bound.y()+bound.height()),
                                    CvScalar.RED,4,
                                    CV_AA, 0
                            );//2 is thickness CV_AA is type of line 0 means no shift

                            //cvSaveImage(++ii + "colorMaskTest.jpg", detectThrs);
                            paint(img, bound.x(), bound.y());
                         }
                        }   
                    }
                    contour = contour.h_next();
                 }
```

Comment: Nice messages :) Couldn't you print some representation of `contour` in each loop iteration ?